# SOS license unity expiring

Tags: unity-game-engine

My license is expiring in 5 days in unity I have no idea how to renew it I pressed a few buttons but still, I don't wanna delete it or something.
Help please.

[image]

:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a local license on your machine. You can create a new one any time you want.

Comment: But wont everything delete or no?

Comment: No. If you have a Plus or Pro license, you can assign it anytime you want, too.

Comment: I have free version

Comment: Then you don't risk anything.